# Converting an int to an unsigned char for display on a Nokia 5110

Tags: arduino-uno, data-type

I've been working on a small project getting some images displayed in a Nokia 5110 screen via an Arduino. I've been getting it working, but one of the issues I have is that I would like to have a list on integers and convert that an unsigned char array that the display requires. Generally I have something like this which works out of the box.

```
unsigned char src [] PROGMEM = {0x00, 0x00}
```

Surprisingly, I found that this also works

```
unsigned char src [] PROGMEM = {255, 255}
```

But when I have a list like this

```
int src [] = {255,255}
```

and try to convert it to an unsigned char array, things don't display correctly

```
unsigned char new_src[2];

for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    new_src[i] = (unsigned char) src[i];
}
```

When I try to display this, it's clearly broken. I thought simply casting the `int` to an `unsigned char` would be enough (it doesn't work even if I don't cast it).

Here's how I display the array (for 84x48, the above arrays were just an example) :

```
Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(7, 6, 5, 4, 3);
display.drawBitmap(0, 0,  src, 2, 48, BLACK);
display.display();
```

On more note:

The end game is to have a file with a list of ints. I would then read that list of ints into an array and convert it into an unsigned char array and then display that.

Comment: How do you display `src`?

Comment: @EdgarBonet edited into the original post

Comment: 1. What do you mean by “_works_”? 2. Why arrays of length 2? For an 84×48 bitmap you need an array of 528 bytes. 3. Does it still work if the `PROGMEM` arrays are `const`? 4. Why do you want to have a list of `int`? Other than wasting RAM, what does that give you that a list of `uint8_t` doesn't?

Comment: 1. "works" as in displays the image properly. 2. This was just an example for simplicity sake. 3. Yes it still works. 4. Because I'm reading the integer values out of file. 4. My C skills aren't as sharp as your so I'm sorry for wasting RAM. @EdgarBonet

Comment: Besides mentioning it, I don't think @EdgarBonet's point was the extra RAM (or Flash), but on the fact that storing your data as 'unsigned char src [] PROGMEM' works for you - why do not use that?

Comment: @JRobert I'm unable to put them in the Arduino code at compile time. The idea is that I would read a list of ints from a file ( I have several files that I would iterate through) and convert that list to the unsigned char array on each loop iteration. If there's a way to store a unsigned char array in a file and read that directly, I could just as well do that.  I'm trying to automate the process of having to go to a website to convert my bitmap, and then copy the result into my Arduino code. I have the conversion part complete via a Python script and now I'm tryin to get it over to Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that I would read a list of ints from a file ( I have
> several files that I would iterate through) and convert that list to
> the unsigned char array on each loop iteration.

The file could be a stream of bytes just as well as a stream of ints (or uints). If it were, no conversion would need to be done - just read a byte & store it, read a byte & store it, ....  If instead, it is a character representation of values, "37, 150, 8, ...", again, read the characters of one value, convert them to `int8_t` or  `uint8_t` and store them in your byte array. Look up the atoi() or sscanf() functions to do the conversion.